# Java iterator nextIndex pointer

Tags: java, collections

Could you explain behaviour of Iterator result:

```
    ArrayList< String > list = new ArrayList< >(
            Arrays.asList( new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" } ) );
    int i = 0;
    ListIterator< String > iterator = list.listIterator();
    while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        if( ++i == 3 ) {
            System.out.println(
                    iterator.previous() + iterator.nextIndex() );
        }
        System.out.println( iterator.next() + iterator.nextIndex() );
    }
```

The output is: a1 b2 b1 b2 c3 d4
Why third output is "b1" but not "a1"?
I figure the structure

0 1 2 3  element index

a b c d  element value

Comment: `nextIndex` is the index that _would be_ returned by calling `next()`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have a bit change the question

Comment: BTW: you don't need the `new String[] { ... }`, you can simply use `Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Javadoc for [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

> A `ListIterator` has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to `previous()` and the element that would be returned by a call to `next()`.

And [`ListIterator.previous()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous()):

> Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards... **(Note that alternating calls to `next` and `previous` will return the same element repeatedly.)**

You're calling `previous()` between `b` and `c`, which returns the previous element (`b`) and sets the cursor back one position (between `a` and `b`), so that `nextIndex()` now returns `1`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best explained by viewing the index values as the dividing lines between the elements:

```
values:  | a | b | c | d |
indizes: 0   1   2   3   4
```

`next()` returns the element to the right of the index position and increments the index. `previous()` returns the element to the left of the index position and decrements the index.

So in the first iteration, index is `0`, so `next()` returns `a` and updates the index to `1`.

In the second iteration, index is `1`, so `next()` returns `b` and updates the index to `2`.

In the third iteration, you first call `previous()`, which returns `b` (left of the position 2) and updates the index to `1` (which is returned by `nextIndex()`).

Then you call `next()`, which returns `b` again (right of the position 1) and updates the index to `2`.